# convert for statement to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have for loop

```
ll = []
for x in l:
    if type(x) == str:
        for y in expandStr(x):
            ll.append(y)
    else:
        ll.append(x)
```

ant to convert it into list comprehension, but get a syntax error

```
ll = [y for x in expandStr(x) if type(x) == str else x for x in l]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are either adding all results of another function (requiring a loop) *or* adding `x` itself, you need to add another loop with a conditional iterable source:

```
ll = [value for x in l for value in (expandStr(x) if isinstance(x, str) else (x,))]
```

So if `x` is not a string, the code uses a single-element tuple as the loop source for the nested loop. Without a list comprehension that would look like:

```
ll = []
for x in l:
    nested_source = expandStr(x) if isinstance(x, str) else (x,)
    for y in nested_source:
        ll.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` within list comprehensions is only used as a filter, like this:

```
[something for element in sequence if condition]
```

The condition is then used as a filter to filter out all elements from the sequence that don’t meet that condition.

If you want to change what item is placed in the list depending on the list element, then you need to adjust the `something` expression. Here, you can use the ternary expression syntax:

```
something if condition else something_else
```

In your case, you want to either *add one* element, or *extend by a list* of elements. This is not possible directly, so you have to choose a common ground of always extending by a list of elements. So you have to place the one element into a one-element-list which you can then loop through again:

```
[ y for x in l for y in (expandStr(x) if isinstance(x, str) else [x]) ]
#   ^^^^^^^^^^
#   loop through the elements in l
#
#                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^                            ^^^
#                        if x is a string, use the sequence that `expandStr` returns;
#                        otherwise just use a 1-element list with the original value
#
#              ^^^^^
#              loop through the sequence that is returned by the ternary expression
#
# ^
# and place that in the final result list
```